# Jquery adds an extra closing tag to span on .text() method

Tags: jquery, text, html

I'm having a problem with jquery .text(), .html() methods.
When I click on specific button to change content of span element, it adds an extra closing tag, which is visible only in tools such as firebug.

Here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kbsRp/
Click on button and inspect the span tag, you'll see that it added an extra closing tag.

```
<span>updated text</span>
updated text</span>
```

Does anybody know, how to prevent this bug? 
It is really annoying in most cases.

Comment: I don't see this error on the provided jsfiddle ?

Comment: It seems to be working just fine in jsfiddle. Inspecting element only shows one closing tag.

Comment: It is working correctly in Chrome.

Comment: Try clicking once again, twice on that button, you'll see the result

Comment: @LadoLomidze I tried many times and it is working fine and shows valid markup in firebug

Comment: Also notice your example doesn't resemble your fiddle.

Comment: @Lado Lomidze Seem OK for me, in jsfiddle and a local test!

Comment: Can we see your actual code? Do you have a live example we can look at?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in chrome's web inspector, which is why the firefox people aren't seeing it. You can verify correct state in chrome by manually traversing the dom, which shows that the web inspector is lying:

[image]

Note to test, you need to change the active frame from the dropdown to `result( fiddle.jshell.net )`. Otherwise the queries are ran on the main window.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an id to target the span and the `html()` function yo avoid the error.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("span#mine").html("updated text");
    return false;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kbsRp/2/

Comment: Me too, but that's just a bug in chromes web inspector. If you traverse the dom manually, you will see.

Comment: Here is the screen shot, what I get. http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg41/scaled.php?server=41&filename=spanz.png&res=landing

Btw, I also try with .html() method, but instead of id, I had to use class, so, this method is not working for me, unfortunately .